# Enable 'upload' and 'new folder' in elFinder under IIS windows environment

Tags: php, elfinder

I installed `elFinder` to my `IIS 7.0` with `php 7.0`, followed by install guide.

But I cannot find `write permission` required action such as - "Upload files", "New folder" in context menu.
 [image]

By response from connector's response, `"writes":0`, so I it caused by root folder is locked.

But I don't how can unlock and enable these features.

I tried to compare another environment with `apache` + `php` at windows.  It works.

Files that I installed is same to original `repo condition`.
When I checked upload folder (default value: elfinder/files) is also normal - it's permission is full control to `IIS_User`.

Which point that my should check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve it.

The problem was that it require IUser permission not IIS_User.
When I add IUser to elfiner's upload folder, it works well.

Comment: Thanks!  To be specific you only need write permission for `IUSR` account on the files directory.

Comment: See [PHP on IIS 7.5/W2K8 using IUSR Account not IIS_APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool](https://serverfault.com/questions/410585) to use App Pool.